# What might cause last item in a jquery style accordion not to close?

Tags: jquery

Markup works fine if I pull the code outside my app and test it, however, once its inside my app, the last item in my accordion will open onclick, but not close.

Comment: Assumption: you're not seeing unhandled javascript exceptions?

Comment: post the html you're having the problem with?

Comment: @james: no. I'm using Firefox error console and no errors. Funny thing is that Chrome will expand the menu but not collapse it back. FF does neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell based on the as far given information. You may want to check if the returned HTML is syntactically valid and syntactically suits in the place where it is been inserted. E.g. are all tags correctly nested and opened/closed? That is namely a pretty common cause of those kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on nesting. I had an unclosed <i> tag which was the culprit!